# Proving associativity in propositional logic

Tags: propositional-calculus

$(p∧q) ∧ r ⊢ p ∧ (q∧r)$

In the sequent above, the only thing that happens is switching brackets between p&q  and r, to q&r and separating out p. I could use the elimination rule between p&q and r, and get these separately, combine them with the introduction rule to get the conclusion.. But what step do I take to replace the brackets from p&q to q&r? Is their a rule that would help me move brackets?

Comment: The "rule that would help me move brackets" is the [associativity property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property#Propositional_logic) : but it seems that you have to prove it.

Comment: As Mauro says: moving the brackets is typically a basic rule ... and it is typically not derivable from other rules of boolean algebra ... but it all depends on what rules you *do* have: so, which rules *can* or must you use?  Maybe you have to give a formal proof but then once again: what rules are given to you to use?

Comment: See the post [Natural deduction: Derive (ϕ ∨ ψ) ∨ σ → ϕ ∨ (ψ ∨ σ)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1424116/natural-deduction-derive-phi-lor-psi-lor-sigma-to-phi-lor-psi-lor-sigma).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to prove it formally, you have to stay at the formal rules of the syntax, like e.g. :

> The set well-formed propositional formulas is the smallest set $X$ with the properties
>
> > *(i)* $p_i ∈ X, i ∈ \mathbb N$,
>
> *(ii)* if $ϕ,ψ ∈ X$, then $(ϕ ∧ ψ) ∈ X$, and so on.

Thus, the correct formula will be :

> $((p \land q) \land r)$,

and the proof will be :

1) $(p \land q)$ --- from premise by $\land$-elim

2) $r$ --- from premise by $\land$-elim

3) $p$ --- from 1) by $\land$-elim

4) $q$ --- from 1) by $\land$-elim

5) $(q \land r)$ --- from 4) and 2) by $\land$-intro

and so on...